# How to change the href tag by only replacing some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I try to replace a `href` if somebody calls the page from iOS. The problem is that the JavaScript doesn't replace only the searched text, but replaces all the initial link. For example:

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class='dynamicLink'>test</a>
```

when iOS phone or tablet to change in this link

```html
 <a href="http://ios+example.com" class='dynamicLink'>test</a>
```

But the JavaScript replace all

```html
 <a href="http://ios+" class='dynamicLink'>test</a>
```

Did somebody know the problem

```js
window.onload = function changeLinks() {
    var href = "http://ios+"
    var links =
        document.getElementsByClassName('dynamicLink');
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].href = href.replace('http://', "http://ios+");
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].href = href.replace('http://', "http://");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you expect that code to do...sorry but the explanation is quite messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `href.replace(...` to replace the link  but `href` is defined above as `var href = "http://ios+"`

Try with this way :

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href = links[i].href.replace('http://',"http://ios+");
  }
```

Or even this, to actually use this `href`

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href = links[i].href.replace('http://', href);
  }
```

Comment: God bless you Thank you very much, I did not know where the problem was